# Insights InstrumentationKey not populated after assignment in global.asax.cs

Tags: azure-application-insights, .net-4.6.1

I have a `.NET Framework 4.6.1` Web API solution which uses these Nuget packages:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="net461" />
```

In the `global.asax.cs` I have this code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"Insights-{EnvironmentConfig.EnvironmentName}"];

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

I can confirm that the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` value retrieval does indeed retrieve a valid Insights key.

In the controllers I have:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);

    [Route("api/DoSomething")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            // stuff happens
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            telemetryClient.TrackException(ex); // does not log
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

If I put a stop point at `// stuff happens` (there is actual code there, of course) and inspect the `telemetryClient` I can see the `InstrumentationKey` property is empty. This means I need to add a line everywhere I instantiate the `TelemetryClient` class and deliberately populated it.

How can I get it to be populated from `global.asax.cs` onwards?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with both appsetting property `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` & `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings` I am able to view the Instrumentation key in `TelemetryConfiguration` & **logs** over `Application Insights`.

We are adding our instrumentation key in `TelemetryConfig` which is available in `Telemetryconfig.`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{    
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"Insights-{EnvironmentConfig.EnvironmentName}"];
    
        //TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"Insights-{EnvironmentConfig.EnvironmentName}"];
    
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
 }
```

[image]

[image]